# recommended reports format for web application

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I am developing web application with `bootstrap` and `angularjs` as front-end, and perhaps java or `nodejs` as a back-end.

And next step is to make reports functionality. Which technology should I choose for reports template and for report? In which format should I store it in database?